# UIBarButtonItem value(forKey: key) cannot get view any more

Tags: swift

I'v used this code to get frame of a uibarbuttonitem:

```
popoverPC.sourceRect = ((mybarbuttonitem.value(forKey:"view") as AnyObject).frame)!
```

and it worked well in swift 2.

Now, after I update my code to swift 3, my app crashed with error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value. Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, you can't use `value(forKey:)` to do that anymore :(

Assuming that your `popoverPC` is a `UIPopoverPresentationController`, you can use the `barButtonItem` property to set the anchor of the popover:

```
popoverPC.barButtonItem = mybarbuttonitem
```